# Why does my client not like my ranking design?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

[image: #1 Visual Aid]

My client has an issue with the design concerning *Ranks*. To be clear, he still wants to show the users rank, but says my design is overwhelming to the user. **Does my client have a point?**

If so, how else should I show the users rank in a more pleasant and effective way?

Comment: As a quick suggestion, the rank is taking up too much room. It's almost as big as the avatar...

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of the visual context? Where on your page does this appear? What are the other elements on the page?

Comment: This appear in the nav. I'll edit my question later when I have access to my work computer.... There are no other elements at the current moment...

Comment: How are we supposed to know why YOUR client doesn't like YOUR design? Shouldn't you ask HIM?

Answer (score 6):

yes i think he has a point , as the ranking looks like as if its the user title .
i think you can make small container for the ranking like badge ..colored according to his level , showing only the ranking number without "points" .

may be something like this 
[image]

Comment: Would you mind providing a picture of what you mean?